# What does this template literal syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

Today I stumbled across some JavaScript code that I've never seen before.
The format appears to be something like:

```
something`Hello ${world}`;
```

Now I know what the `` quotes do, and I am familiar with the new ES6 ${variable} syntax. 
But it doesn't look like anything I've seen before, and I don't understand how this doesn't generate an error.
What is "something" and how / why does this even work?